# -{footer}- que significa esto?

Tags: variables

Hola tengo una duda y es que significa esta sentencia -{footer}- , o encontre en un  desarrollo , pero no tengo la menor idea de que es , creo que es una variable , no estoy seguro ya que yo las hago $var o let var o var o  int var . Por favor podrian ayudarme

esto es una parte del código , me dicen que está hecho con JS y se accede mediante SSH

```
<section class="row squareBanner" id="contactanos">
        <h1>Anúnciate con nosotros.</h1>
        <p><a href="paquetes.html" class="btn btn-lg">Ver paquetes</a></p>
    </section>
    -{footer}-
```

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje?, nos muestras por favor el código mínimo necesario para comprender mejor tu duda?

Comment: Por favor el código que haga falta va en tu pregunta, edita y ahi escribe lo que haga falta